# Open/close gate

Tags: wireless

This would seem like a problem that could be solved by buying it at a store, but it doesn’t seem to exist.  I have a fenced backyard with two gates.  When I let the dog out I’d like to be able to look at two green lights to ensure that the gates are closed.  (One light for each gate)I built a simple hard wired device for one closeup gate (using an adapter and a couple of leds) but the other gate is farther away and I’d like to have a wireless unit.  There are plenty of products that send signals if a gate is BEING opened, but I want some thing that would indicate if the gate is opened or shut. Any suggestions/help/how-tos would be much appreciated.
Bud

Comment: Normally closed endswitch in "close" position? And then any of cheap 433Mhz links from Ali....

Comment: Can you see the other gate from the house? The simplest wireless solution is putting a flashing indicator LED —one flash per second if it's open— at the gate.